# Flink: How to restart Flink taskmanager on windows?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

My goal is to kill Flink task manager and then restart it on Windows. This is needed to stimulate error in Flink so that I can see checkpoint work. I have managed to find the task manager PID by looking up the PID against the port it listens to. So killing that PID should kill taskmanager but I am unable to find a way to restart Flink taskmanager on windows because the taskmanager script is a shell script.
Please help me in below two queries.

1. How to restart Flink taskmanager on windows? Do we need to install cygwin and use it. Will it work? If cygwin works please provide steps to proceed to restart taskmanager.
2. Is there a more elegant way to know the taskmanager PID on windows?

Comment: Well if you see the check pointing has completed successfully on the dashboard, that means it most probably worked. If you are going to test every core flink functionality, you have a very long road ahead.

Comment: Do u have the answer or not?

Comment: How did you start the task manager in the first place? Why can't you do that again?

Comment: task manager is started using a script called start-cluster.bat which starts flink server including taskmanager. But because of some reason if flink taskmanager dies then on linux we can restart using taskmanager.sh start . I am not sure on windows. hence he query above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If task manager is down on windows and Job manager is running then one can start task manager simply by executing %FLINK_HOME%\bin\start-cluster.bat. It will just restart the taskmanager.
2. When start-cluster.bat is executed it opens two terminals(cmd windows) running two Java processes. The second window belongs to taskmanager so by doing ctrl+c on that window one can kill taskmanager. Also the first window belongs to Jobmanager.